# Can I retrain Google translate API model?

Tags: google-translate

I am using Google translate API for regional language Gujarati.

Translation accuracy is not satisfactory, is there any way I can improve the accuracy level of this model?

Can I retrain the model to improve accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no way to re-train a model without access to the original model.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, however, you could specify a [model](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#specifying_a_model) for your translations to have different results.